# jQuery select2: auto complete not work in tag design

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I work with select2 (v +4) plugin and have This code for fetch data from json file and show with tagging design/method:

JS Code:

```
$(".tags-select").select2({
  // enable tagging
  tags: true,
    
  // max tags is 3
  maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    
  // loading remote data
  // see https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/444cr",
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="tags-select form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="tag1" selected="selected">tag1</option>
  <option value="tag2" selected="selected">tag2</option>
</select>
```

In action auto complete not work for me!!

[DEMO](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) in original page

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/59Lbxvyc/) For my code

how do fix this prolem?!